# How do I check if a key in a record exists?

Tags: applescript

I discovered that if I try to access a field in a record, e.g.:

```
set track_album to (|Album| of t)
```

And that field does not exist, AppleScript throws an error.  How can I check if that field exists first?  Or how to let it fail silently?  (Whichever is the best practice.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
set track_album to album of (t & {album:default})
```

it will be set to album if it exists or default if not.

or

```
try
album of t
on error -1728
default
end try
```